# How to resize the dash for desktop from terminal?

Tags: unity-dash

I had installed Ubuntu 13.10 I want to know how to re-size the dash size to the desktop through terminal. So please let me know i have tried every setting but not fulfilled.

Comment: Close voters, this question has answer and the GUI freeze is already in place. There is no need to close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the "size" in the **com.canonical.Unity** scheme, **form-factor** key with the [gsettings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gsettings.1.html) command.

**1)** If you want the dash **"Half Screen"**...

Open a Terminal and type:

- `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Desktop'`

[image]

**2)** If you want the dash **"Full Screen"**...

The Terminal command would be:

- `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity form-factor 'Netbook'`

[image]

**Note: You can also set the form-factor in Automatic**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This has been tested on 13.10

I don't know if you can do it from terminal, but, you can resize the dash as shown in the images below.  Just click on the little circled rectangle, and you should be able to resize it to full window, and it will stay the same even after shutdown and restart.

**Note**: Keep in mind that this might change once the official release is out.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]