# Disable unity launcher to launch in full screen?

Tags: unity, launcher

When I press the application launcher it come in full screen and it has blurry background. I want it small and transparrent...because it is laggy! I don't know how to say what I want. I searched on the internet but I can't found it. I did it before but I can't remembor how did I found it

Comment: Does this http://askubuntu.com/questions/354278/how-to-resize-the-dash-for-desktop-from-terminal/354312#354312 help?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You can either install Compiz Settings Manager or Ubuntu Tweak(Unity Tweak if you are in Ubuntu 13.10) and disable/enable the dash blur.

[image]

[image]